# how to do a javascript confirm dialog if a radio button is checked, with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, webforms, radio-button

I have two radio buttons like so

```
<input type="radio" name="rush" value="yes" />
<input type="radio" name="rush" value="no" checked="checked" />
```

What I want to do is when the form submit button is clicked, check if 'yes' is selected.

If it is, show a javascript confirm dialog

I've gotten this far, but am stuck, any help would be appreciated.

```
$("form.shipping").submit(function() {

    if($("input[name='rush']".attr("value") === "yes")
    {
        if (confirm("Rush orders are subject to an upcharge. (Just wanted to make sure you read the note). Is this ok?"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: With those changes it is still not working?

Comment: yes with the above code I still never get a confirm, bummer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are binding something to the `click` event of a button. You probably want to bind it to the `submit` event of the form. Besides that, you misspelled `input.sumbit-button` in your selector.

**EDIT**: [Here](http://jsbin.com/izixa) is a working version of what you want. Your errors were:

- You were probably not wrapping your code around `document.ready`. This is important if your script is included at the top of the page, as anything you write that is not wrapped in this event will execute before the DOM elements are created. So you would be binding events to nothing. The `document.ready` event takes care of that by firing as soon as the DOM is fully loaded.
- You had a missing closing `)` right before `.attr`. You should probably look into tools like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to debug your javascript, as it is trivial to find these kind of things with it.
- You were checking the value of the radio button, but it was always evaluating to true because you need to filter it out to only get the [`:checked`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked) one.

So, the working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form.shipping").submit(function() {
        if($("input[name='rush']").is(":checked")) {
            return confirm("Rush orders are subject to an upcharge.
            (Just wanted to make sure you read the note). Is this ok?");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I did have the document ready but neglected to post it :-( my bad

Comment: Ah. Roger. I'm going to leave the warning in there anyways as a warning to anyone that reads this later on. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Does it fail in multiple browsers?  I've seen reports of some odd bugs in IE7 where confirm() didn't execute in an onclick or onsubmit event handler.

Answer (score 0):

your selector "input[name='rush']" will return both inputs, you need "input[name='rush']:checked" as Paolo Bergantino suggested